# Hibernate generates and sends malformed query to SQL server

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2012

Below is the SQL trace in SQL Server 2012 of a hibernate detached criteria:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P0 bit,@P1 datetime,@P2 datetime,@P3 int,@P4 int',N'WITH query AS (select this_.cid as cid9_0_, this_.ms, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__gfrom as msgfrom9_0_, this_.msgto as msgto9_0_, this_.msgcc as msgcc9_0_, this_.msubject as msubject9_0_, this_.body as body9_0_, this_.createdate as createdate9_0_, this_.maildate as maildate9_0_, this_.expirydate as expirydate9_0_, this_.mailsent as mailsent9_0_, this_.remarks as remarks9_0_, this_.html as html9_0_ from [mail_queue] this_ where this_.mailsent= @P0  and (this_.maildate is null or this_.maildate<= @P1 ) and (this_.expirydate is null or this_.expirydate>= @P2 )) SELECT * FROM query WHERE __hibernate_row_nr__ >=  @P3  AND __hibernate_row_nr__ <  @P4 ',1
select @p1
```

The query is malformed at `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__gfrom as msgfrom9_0_`. The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr_` part is generated by hibernate for fetching n results based on the limit parameters passed by me.

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria, 0, 250)
```

This was causing the issue(though it shouldn't be) and when I removed the parameters then the issue doesn't occur:

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria)
```

But I need to set the limit as I don't want thousands of records to be fetched. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting
I've been using PagingAndSortingRepository along with SQL server (though not 2012) with great success.

Comment: I am using hibernate 4 and I can only access  hibernateTemplate to execute query. With this I am doing pagination by providing first and max results as parameters which was working fine in spring, hibernate 3.

Comment: Stop using a Hibernate version that is 10 years old. Newer Hibernate versions most probably fixed the problem in the `LimitHandler`, which you can also override through the `Dialect`, already.